# Product of two Lipschitz functions is not Lipschitz examples

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Suppose we have a $(X,d)$ a metric space which is not bounded. Then take $f,g : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ both defined with $f(x)=g(x)=x$. Then $f$ and $g$ are Lipschitz, but $(fg)(x)=x^2$ is not Lipschitz.

> Could someone please give me more such examples where there are two Lipschitz functions but their product is not Lipschitz **given** $(X,d)$ is not bounded.

Comment: $f(x) = g(x) = -x$.

Comment: On a general metric space, you can probably take $f(x) = g(x) = d(x,x_0)$ with $x_0$ fixed.